# generating all substrings and maintaining count of similar substrings

Tags: c++, substring

I am provided with a string say S. I need to find the count of each unique substring.

```
  like I am having S="aaa" then all the substrings of S are
  {("a"),("a"),("a"),("aa"),("aa"),("aaa")}.
```

So I need the count of unique substrings. In this case substring "a" has count 3 and "aa" has count 2 and "aaa" has count 1. I dont know how to use map in STL. I am new to programming in cplusplus. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to _implement_ [`std::map<><`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), just use it.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  Is there any other way to implement the same?

Comment: @VivekPuri To *implement* `std::map` means to write a complete definition of `std::map`. That is already done in the standard C++ library. The definition is in the header `<map>`. You only need to make use of it.

Comment: @Mike Kinghan but how can i maintain the count of each substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

learn **map** from then tutorial http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57446-stl-maps/ and simply increment the counter value by writing the code

```
map<string,int> substrings;
```

when you generate a substring named string_name just write

```
substrings[string_name]++;
```

It will increment the counter of each key value if it already exits otherwise it will generate a new one.

Comment: Yes this is what, i was searching for. Thank you so much.